# Spring Data Mongo Custom Repository Query with ObjectID

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongo query I want to implement as a Spring Mongo Repository

```
db.collection.find({ 'items': 
    { $elemMatch: { 
        'refund.$id' :  ObjectId('5638cab2e4b07ff212618d7e') 
        } 
    }
})
```

My Repository interface is

```
@Query("{ 'items': { $elemMatch: { 'refund.$id' :  ObjectId(?0) } } }")
RMA findRMAByItemRefund(String refundId);
```

It throws JSONParseException

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{ 'items': { $elemMatch: { 'refund.$id' :  ObjectId("_param_0") } } }
                                       ^
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:216)
```

Comment: Are you trying to bind  the parameter `refundId` to the query parameter `refund.$id` ? If `refund` is another entity you can try `refund.id` since Spring does the id convert stuff by itself

Comment: Yes. It works @JoaoEvangelista Spring handles the convert. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
@Query("{ 'items': { $elemMatch: { 'refund.id' :  ?0 } } }")
RMA findRMAByItemRefund(String refundId);
```

From my experience, `?0` should standalone and not used as a mongo function parameter.

Also, is `$id` your own assumption or the field is actually stored as `$id`. If not, I will go with `refund.id`

Answer (score 4):

As the accepted solution did not yield any results in my case, I had to find another solution, that was:

Instead of using the autogenerated query functionality defined via `@Query(...)` I opted for manually building the `DBObject` used to query mongo, and defining the functionality as a `default` implementation in the interface, thus keeping it "clean" 
(`"` - because had to introduce a `_query` method)

**Note:** This solution only works in **Java 1.8**+

```
public interface SomeRepository extends MongoRepository<SomeEntity, String> {

    @Query("{'nestedEntity._id': ?0}")
    SomeEntity findByNestedEntityId_DoesntWork(String nestedEntityId);

    @Query("?0")
    SomeEntity _query(DBObject query);

    default SomeEntity findByNestedEntityId(String nestedEntityId) {
        DBObject queryObject = BasicDBObjectBuilder
            .start("nestedEntity._id", new ObjectId(nestedEntityId))
            .get();

        return this._query(queryObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess my problem was a little different, but since I couldn't find answer anywhere, I believe it's worth mentioning.
Basically I wanted to do the search by ObjectId AND userId, so here's what I've done:

```java
@Query("{ '_id': ?0, 'userId': ?1 }")
T findByObjectIdAndUserId(final ObjectId objectId, final Long userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the example object on `mongo` document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c052a43f14008522c1c90c8"), 
    "_class" : "com.gdn.payment.report.entity.ReportDocument", 
    "status" : "DONE", 
    "report" : {
        "id" : ObjectId("5c0508bcf14008460015eb07"), 
        "startDate" : NumberLong(1542795843188), 
        "endDate" : NumberLong(1543568857157), 
        "fields" : [
            "customerInfo.billingAddress.streetAddress", 
            "customerInfo.name", 
            "items[*].name", 
            "orderId", 
            "type"
        ]
    }
}
```

You can make the repository method for searching `report.id` only by using `ObjectId` data type, I've tried using just string and it cannot work, here are my repository method:

```
Page<ReportDocument> findByReport_id(ObjectId reportId, Pageable pageable)
```

for creating `ObjectId` you can do it using:

```
new ObjectId({input-reportId-string})
```

Comment: If the $elemMatch in the accepted solution isn't working for you, then try this solution out. It works wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Spring Data [Derived Queries](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries). You can also use [QueryDsl](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-mongodb) on top.

Then you'd be able to write much more complex queries without having to deal with secondary issues such as query syntax and parsing.